# How to create a placeholder array in Google Sheets?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets

This is what I am trying to achieve. The first row has five times the value x spread over five columns with an x in each column. The same applies to the value y that appears one row below.

[image]

How do I create the two rows with a formula where I do not know how many columns the x row consists of? Can you explain to me how it works? I've seen it before, but i don't understand how it works.. .

[image]

SUMPLACEHOLDER() is NOT working madeup custom function

Good to say. The row with the x values must always be hard coded. So you cannot generate these values with a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function SUMPLACEHOLDER() is probably a custom function? You should be able to do this with built-in formulas only. See if this helps

```
=index(split(rept({"X"; "Y"}&"^", 5), "^"))
```

Note: 5 indicates the number of columns you want to use for the output.

### EDIT

If that doesn't work you can try this custom function (paste it in the script editor and save)

```
const createMatrix = (sourceArray, delimiter, valuesString) => {
const arr = sourceArray.split(delimiter);
const rows = valuesString.split(delimiter).map(value => new 
Array(arr.length).fill(value))
return [arr].concat(rows)
```

}

Then in your spreadsheet enter

```
=createMatrix("A, B, C, D, E", ", ", "test")
```

[image]

The first parameter (string) are the values (separated with a delimiter) that will appear in the first row. The second parameter is the delimiter used to separate the values in the first parameter and the third parameter is the value that needs to be repeated (depending on the length of the values entered in the first parameter). If more rows are needed, append the value to be repeated to the last parameter (using the same delimiter)

```
=createMatrix("A, B, C, D, E", ", ", "test one, test two")
```

### [image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your answer assumes that you know how many values are in the row with the x values. Is that correct? You should not assume that. The x values can also sometimes be other than x. I do not say that in my question, but I just want to be able to enter values there that are different each time.

Comment: Now that I know the rept function exists I think I can solve it myself so indirectly you have answered my question. :-)

Comment: @Fabian: I updated my answer. See if the custom function works for you?